# Compare class types in C++

Tags: c++, casting, compare

I need to compare two classes, more exactly their types.
I wrote the following code:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

class Engine
{
public:
    template <class T>
    T addComponent();
};

template <class T>
T Engine::addComponent()
{
    Base* isRight = dynamic_cast<Base*>(T);
    if (!isRight)
        throw("Error!");

    return T();
}
```

And then I call it

```
int main()
{
    Engine engine = Engine();
    Derived derived = engine.addComponent<Derived>();
}
```

Well, I know, `dynamic_cast` works only on instances of the class. I hope you know a solution.

Comment: It isn't clear at all what you're trying to do, but you might want to look at [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

Comment: Also, throwing a string literal is a _terrible_ idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).  And since it's a static thing, you can do this check entirely at compile time:

```
template <class T>
T Engine::addComponent()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, "T doesn't derive from Base!");

    return T();
}
```